# Eloquent query in custom config file (/config) Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Trying to fire the following Eloquent query in a custom config file which is present in: `/config` directory in Laravel 5:

```
'array_name' =>(App\MyApp\Models\ModelName::lists('column_name', 'column_name')),
```

Getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on a non-object in /path/to/the/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 3132

Comment: What do you see in Model.php in line 3132? My version of Laravel has different version of code. 

Error itself means that some object in null in there. It can be that Laravel has not properly initialized itself when parsin config files.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, but is their any way In laravel 5, to fire an eloquent query in custom config file? because in laravel 4.3, firing a eloquent query in custom config file was quite easy

Comment: Config file is not a place for querying the db. Do the job in a service provider for example.

Comment: @ Jarek Tkaczyk how to use query in provider and call this in config?

Answer (score 0):

The config files that depend on database must be loaded lazily. Just put them inside a new `config.lazy` folder next to `config` folder and add the following method inside your `app/Providers/COnfigServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
{
    $envConfigPath = config_path() . '/../config.lazy';
    $config = app('config');
    foreach (\Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::create()->files()->name('*.php')->in($envConfigPath) as $file)
    {
        $key_name = basename($file->getRealPath(), '.php');
        $old_values = $config->get($key_name) ?: [];
        $new_values = require $file->getRealPath();
        $config->set($key_name, array_replace_recursive($old_values, $new_values));
    }
}
```