# how do we access data from database or other files in app.php of the config folder in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

how do we access data from database or other files in app.php of the config folder in laravel 5 ? I want to access other file outside the application

Comment: Can you please be more explicit with your question? Perhaps a senario of what you want exactly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I want to fetch a key for encryption basically, and put that value in the 'key' value of the return array.

Comment: i want to set the 'key' in return array of config/app.php from another server or database or file.

Answer (score 0):

For access data from database see running a select query Example:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', [1]);
```

The select method will always return an array of results.

For access data from another file see [view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views) and [here](http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller).

Comment: db statements don't seem to work in app.php file in the config folder

Comment: You may find your solution [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203532/eloquent-query-in-custom-config-file-config-laravel-5)