# laravel 5.3 custom config file with database or elequent access

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a custom config file in config folder. I need to run database query or access Laravel 5.3 eloquent on this file so that it loads on run time. For example

```html
$site_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$siteData = Site::whereSiteUrl($site_name)->first();

//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($siteData);
//echo "</pre>";
//exit;


if($siteData)
{
 //echo $siteData->getOriginal('db_password'); exit;
  $dbhost = $siteData->db_host;
  $dbname = $siteData->db_name;
  $username = $siteData->db_user;
  $password = $siteData->getOriginal('db_password');
  $template = $siteData->site_theme;
}
else
{
 
 
 App::error(function($exception, $code)
 {
   Log::error($exception);
   return 'Sorry! Something is wrong with this account!';
  //return Response::view('test.error500', array(), 500);
  
 });
}

 //echo $password; exit;

DB::disconnect('mysql');
DB::disconnect('db_lk_prefix');
DB::disconnect('db_coll_prefix');

Config::set('database.connections.mysql', array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $dbhost,
    'database'  => $dbname,
    'username'  => $username,
    'password'  => $password,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
));   
Config::set('database.connections.db_lk_prefix', array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $dbhost,
    'database'  => $dbname,
    'username'  => $username,
    'password'  => $password,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => 'lk_',
));   
Config::set('database.connections.db_coll_prefix', array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $dbhost,
    'database'  => $dbname,
    'username'  => $username,
    'password'  => $password,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => 'coll_',
)); 

DB::reconnect('mysql');
DB::reconnect('db_lk_prefix');
DB::reconnect('db_coll_prefix');
```

But it is not working at all in 5.3 but works in 4.2. It is showing `Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null in`

Can anybody help with proper example?

Comment: Where do you need to use the `$site_name` and/or `$siteData` variables? In a view, controller, elsewhere?

Comment: @ tptcat it be used every where

Comment: Once it's set, is it possible it can change during the session?

Comment: no this will not be changed and there will no session...actually site name will be used for multi site purpose and database connection will be changed also as per site name

Comment: I have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203532/eloquent-query-in-custom-config-file-config-laravel-5 but not working at all

Comment: How are you expecting to query the database to set which database connection to use? Can you give more detail about what you're actually trying to accomplish? That would help a lot.

Comment: Please check my updated version. this is working fine in Laravel 4.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124801/discussion-between-madankundu-and-tptcat).

Comment: Anybody know this matters?

Comment: One one knows laravel...very sad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make database query inside a config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789071/how-to-make-database-query-inside-a-config-file)