# How to use DB Facades in config file?

Tags: php, laravel

The error message is: `A facade root has not been set.`

[image]

[image]

Any advice is really helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent error: A facade root has not been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418810/eloquent-error-a-facade-root-has-not-been-set)

Comment: try only.
use \DB

Comment: what you are trying to do , what emc.php does and where it is located in laravel app ?

Comment: Please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789071/how-to-make-database-query-inside-a-config-file for your solution

Comment: Please see below url for your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789071/how-to-make-database-query-inside-a-config-file

Comment: @C2486 ems.php is located in config folder of laravel root directory, and ems.php used as a config file.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this:

Leave a default or null value in your `config/database.php` file. Create a new service provider (either with the artisan command or manually)

```
php artisan make:provider DatabaseConfigProvider
```

Then add the new provider to the $providers array in your config/app.php file.

Finally add the following code to the boot() method.

```
public function boot()
{
    $result= \DB::select('select version() as version')[0];
    $this->app['config']->put('database.connections.mysql.version', $result->version);
}
```

The key in the put() argument can be whatever you want.

Comment: Finnally I changed the config file approach to database approach .   Anyway，thanks for you help.